# Bootstrap tabs not switching

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css"> 

<script src="css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs id="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
This is the text of tab1.
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
<p>This is the text of tab2.</p>
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
<p>This is the text of tab3.</p>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

I've tried everything and basically it just won't switch tabs. I've even tried copying source code from other sites and it still won't work.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2N7Q/1/ ... there is a missing `"` in `<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">`

Comment: bootstrap version used?

Comment: The new one I recently just downloaded it think its possible that the scripts are in the wrong place But I will check and then come back if they are working.

Comment: also there is no need to inlcude the min and dev versions... only one of them is required

Comment: can you check the browser console to see whether there are any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the jQuery verison 1.6, bootstrap used [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which was added only in jQuery verision 1.7. So upgrade jQuery to a newer version and it should be fine

With jQuery 1.6.4: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2N7Q/2/) - not working because of error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

Demo: [jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2N7Q/3/), [jQuery 1.9](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z2N7Q/4/)

Comment: THANK YOU I updated JQurey and also added <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">

Luv you all :3

Answer (score 2):

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs id="tabs">
```

you are missing a closing " on your class
it should be

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
```

see if that fixes it